# How to set first alphabet is in upper case by default in android

Tags: android

I want to fill a form where Name,Address,City,some fields are there.How can I set that if user enter first name or something another field then first letter should be in caps by default in android.please help me.

thank you

Comment: Where you need first letter should be capital? While user entering text ? or While you are saving the form ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can easily set the inputType on your EditText:

```
<!-- in your xml --> 
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

or

```
//(programmatically)
yourEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

Here the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType).